# How to use persist values outside Views and Controllers in Rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am a newbie in Rails, i would like to persist a value that comes in as input from a form. So this value is to be used in an adapter class outside of Controllers and Views. I have read cookies and sessions are not the best way to go.

```
# app/controller/somewhere.rb
class MyController > ApplicationController
    def input_capture
       form_value = "xxxxxx"
       ** # i need to do something with this value to access it in the adapter
```

```
# app/adapters/someadapter.rb
class MyAdapter
    def self.some_method
        form_value
```

Comment: Why not use ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely, but if I'm not mistaken you are trying to pass a value from a form into your adapter. In that case you can initialize your adapter in the controller and pass the value, do what you need to do, then return the value.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  private
  def input_capture
    @value = MyAdapter.new(form_value).execute
  end
end

class MyAdapter
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def execute
    #do what you need to do with the @value
    @value
  end
end
```

BTW your controller is not inheriting **ApplicationController** correctly. If that is what you were trying to do, you should do

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
```

instead of

```
class MyController > ApplicationController
```

Also, if you're trying to implement the Adapter design pattern I suggest you read through some documentation and examples on the implementation of the design pattern. Here are some hopefully helpfull links

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter/ruby/example

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-and-testing-the-adapter-design-pattern/

Comment: Thanks! A huge eye opener